How do I calculate the frequency of this 555 Toy Organ circuit (from Mim's Radio Shack book)?
So, I've got the circuit below (from Forest Mim's 555 Radio Shack book), and I want to try to verify the first frequency ( 52 Hz @ .22 uF). I basically don't know what I'm doing, so I'm going to take it slowly...

I think I understand that the way this works is the trigger and threshold pins (6 and 2, same potential here) vary as the circuit charges and discharges - when they are below 3 V, output (on pin 3) goes high, and when it's above 6 V, output is set low. So we need to determine the frequency that this is switching at, yes?
My first naive guess is to just find the RC time constant (i.e. 1/frequency) - that's
$$f=\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{1}{RC}\sim 45~\text{Hz}$$
(Assuming the total resistance is 110k) Not a bad guess, but also not quite right. So I guess what's wrong there is that's assuming the circuit flips when the cap is charged to 1/e, but it actually flips at these 1/3, 2/3 marks. So I'm thinking "potential across the cap starts at zero, and the 555 in the high state. Then it charges, past 1/3, past 2/3, and then the thing flips to the low state, how long does that take?" I think that's
$$V(t)=V_0 (1-e^\frac{-t}{RC})\rightarrow \frac{2}{3}V_0=V_0 (1-e^\frac{-t}{RC})\rightarrow -\frac{1}{3}=-e^\frac{-t}{RC}\rightarrow t=-RC \ln(\frac{1}{3})$$
But that's actually worse, frequency of about 41 Hz. Maybe I'm flipping the directions and I need to just charge to 1/3 V_0, but that's....a frequency of 110 Hz!
[I guess I can try to flip my assumptions around, and ask "how do I get that frequency?", to which the answer is
$$\frac{V}{V_0}\sim 0.54$$
So another way to ask this is "why that potential?" but that actually suggests I'm missing something pretty critical about where the frequency comes from!]

Minor point: it's a fun toy to make, but the ear is quite sensitive to relative frequency between notes. Even with high-precision components, don't expect it to sound nice, especially when playing with another instrument. Synthesizers use quartz crystal oscillators and dividers to get within parts per million of the scale.

Yeah it's true I'm not sure I'm actually going to build the thing, but I had a good time with the sound effect generator (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWrY6RWyQUA&), so I'm considering what the next thing to make is. Maybe tune the caps to hit at least some notes in equal tuning? Maybe attach it to a vibrator and a resonant chamber? Or maybe just move on....

It's still a fun project, and can play a simple tune, but don't expect polyphony.

The equation is in the SE555 datasheet, so I am not sure what your goal is.
\$f = \frac{1.44}{(R_1+2R_2)C}\$
For 100k, 10k, 0.22 uF I get 54.5 Hz
If you want to derive it yourself:
The cap charges through R1 + R2 until it reaches 2/3 of Vcc.
Then
The cap discharges through R2 until it reaches 1/3 of Vcc.
Then the cycle repeats.
The 1/3 and 2/3 thresholds come from three 5k resistors in the IC, that is where the 555 originated.
Your math skills seem to be fairly good; I will let you derive it.

Awesome - if that's the cycle, I bet I can confirm that formula, it's the asymmetry I didn't understand. I guess that's what the transistor in the 555 is doing? When the flip-flop goes high to low, the transistor "opens" and connects 1 to 7, grounding R2 and discharging C1 through R2.

@cduston The asymmetry problem is due to the fact that during the charge cycle you have BOTH R1 and R2 in series, while during the discharge cycle you have ONLY R2, so the ratio in your case can be as high as 10:1 between charge and discharge times. When both R1 and R2 are equal (10K), charge/discharge time ratio is 2:1. The way to make it more symmetrical is to make R1 much smaller than R2 (like 1K), and place the potentiometer as R2. Both can also be increased ten times, while C1-C4 are decreased. Search the web for a schematic with 555 which gives you symmetric cycles, involves 2 diodes.

@cduston I have actually made the simplest "equivalent" schematic of the 555 IC using discrete components, which should make it easier to understand how the 555 works internally. It is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/724917/constructive-input-welcome-simplest-discrete-transistor-based-555-timer-design but 3 guys decided to close it. ANOTHER VERY IMPORTANT NOTE: The placement of the potentiometer in your circuit is not recommended because it will create a short circuit from the +V supply side to the ground through the discharge transistor when you set it to zero ohms.

@EdinFifić: very unfortunate about that other post I would have liked to see it. On the potentiometer hitting zero - my plan is to put a 100 k pot in series with a 50 k resistor, so that shouldn't be a problem. But thanks for the heads up, I might not have noticed that!

Ok, I got the right answer, one clue is that 1/ln(2)~1.44. But the slightly tricky part was solving the diff eq for charging capacitor not from 0, but from 1/3 Vcc. (Of course, it wasn't technically hard, I just couldn't quite think through it without working it out in detail, having never done it before.)

@cduston My 555 schematic is still up there, you can read it, you just can't respond to it, it's not open anymore. If you need to do slight adjustments to each capacitor's charge/discharge time and thus frequency when it is engaged, you could add a small value trimmer (like 1-5kΩ) in series with each capacitor. For duty cycle, period and frequency calculations, there are easy online calculators, one of them being this one: https://ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator

@EdinFifić: I get a "page not found" error on your 555 link, so I can't see anything. But that 555 calculator link is super interesting, thanks!
